# How to convert Null Date into Blank?

Tags: mysql, sql, isnull

I have a table which I'd like to convert Null Date (my date format i.e 2014-02-12) to blank string but an error occurs whenever I do IsNull, I have mysql. Is there away to do it with isnull?

Comment: Do you have a code sample, and what is the data type of the field? Also, are you talking about converting the *output* of a query, or the data in the field itself?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, date_field), '')
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL:

```
 SELECT ISNULL(CAST(date_value AS char),'')
```

or

```
 SELECT ISNULL(DATE_FORMAT(date_value , '%d %m %Y'),'')
```

SQL SERVER:

```
 SELECT ISNULL(CAST(date_value AS VARCHAR(20)),'')
```

Comment: the question state's it's mysql.

Comment: I think Kermit realized that just seconds after posting the comment. heh

Comment: thanks guys, also, I have an issue because my date column is in temporary table? I tried ISNULL(CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), #a.date), ' ') but it can't pop up. Does it not apply for temp table?

Comment: try the other mysql ways first, shouldn't matter if it's in a temp table or not.